# How to manage nested loop in xml while parsing with documentBuilderFactory

Tags: java, xml, xslt, dom

I am parsing an xml file which has nested tag and I am using xsl to match the pattern with the xml  , and my task is to pick all tag value and write it to an csv file I am able to read and write the xml and csv file but , when comes to nested loops the data in the csv file are not coming properly, I am giving my code and w hat I have done..

my  xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<pagedata>
 <pyTemporaryObject>false</pyTemporaryObject> 
 <ResolutionCode>Policy Adjustment Action</ResolutionCode> 
<Origin>DOI</Origin>
<InsuredFName>Buffy</InsuredFName>
<ThirdParty>
<Name>Karen Wallace</Name> 
<Phone>785-296-7829</Phone> 
<State>KS</State> 
<Address1>420 SW 9th Street</Address1> 
<pxObjClass>PCore-Compliance-Commsys-Data-ThirdParty</pxObjClass>  
</ThirdParty>    
</pagedata>
```

my xsl file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" >
<xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
   <xsl:template match="/">
pyTemporaryObject,ResolutionCode,Origin,InsuredFName,Name,Phone,State,Address1,pxObjClass
<xsl:for-each select="//pagedata">
<xsl:value-of select="concat  (pyTemporaryObject,',',ResolutionCode,',',Origin,',',InsuredFName,'&#xA;')"/>
   <xsl:for-each select="//ThirdParty">
<xsl:value-of select="concat   (Name,',',Phone,',',State,',',Address1,',',pxObjClass,'&#xA;')"/>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and my Java class

```
 public class Xml2Csv {

 public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{

        File stylesheet = new File("src/main/resources/newStyle.xsl");
        File xmlSource = new File("src/main/resources/parse.xml");

        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = builder.parse(xmlSource);

        StreamSource stylesource = new StreamSource(stylesheet);
        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance()
                .newTransformer(stylesource);
        Source source = new DOMSource(document);
        Result outputTarget = new StreamResult(new File("src/main/resources/y.csv"));
        transformer.transform(source, outputTarget);

 }
```

}

The csv is coming as

```
pyTemporaryObject|ResolutionCode|Origin|InsuredFName|Name|Phone|State|Address1|pxObjClass
False Policy DOI BUffy // these are the value of the first loop 
john 98766 west ../// these are the values of the second loop
```

But I need the two values to  come to the same  row ...Please help thanks in advnace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you really need to do is move the `xsl:value-of` in the outer `xsl:for-each` into the inner one instead, and change the xpath references to select the parent values accordingly

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" >

   <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:text>pyTemporaryObject,ResolutionCode,Origin,InsuredFName,Name,Phone,State,Address1,pxObjClass&#xA;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:for-each select="//pagedata">
         <xsl:for-each select="ThirdParty">
           <xsl:value-of select="concat(../pyTemporaryObject, ',', ../ResolutionCode, ',', ../Origin, ',', ../InsuredFName)"/>
           <xsl:value-of select="concat(',', Name, ',', Phone, ',', State, ',', Address1, ',', pxObjClass, '&#xA;')"/>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that, if it is possible to have no `ThirdParty` elements, but you still want a row output, try this instead

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" >

   <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:text>pyTemporaryObject,ResolutionCode,Origin,InsuredFName,Name,Phone,State,Address1,pxObjClass&#xA;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:for-each select="//pagedata">
        <xsl:if test="not(ThirdParty)">
           <xsl:value-of select="concat(pyTemporaryObject, ',', ResolutionCode, ',', Origin, ',', InsuredFName, '&#xA;')"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:for-each select="ThirdParty">
           <xsl:value-of select="concat(../pyTemporaryObject, ',', ../ResolutionCode, ',', ../Origin, ',', ../InsuredFName)"/>
           <xsl:value-of select="concat(',',Name, ',', Phone, ',', State, ',', Address1, ',', pxObjClass, '&#xA;')"/>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: the name is concating with the insuredName and second for loop ouput is left shifted by one cell..

Comment: just add an `<xsl;text>,</xsl;text>` after the first `xsl:value-of-select` in the last loop.

Comment: @Mandrek - I editted my answer to add in the missing comma that was causing the issue.